# Implementing Sentry with existing React Native Project

Tags: react-native, sentry

I'm implementing Sentry.io as an issue monitoring service on my existing React Native app. I manage to successfully install Sentry and work through the sentry wizard.

Once I initiate Sentry at the top of App.tsx my local development environment (IOS simulator) is significantly slower and is causing my application to effectively become unusable.

Has anyone experienced this?

react-native >= 0.60

I'm initiating Sentry at the top of my App.tsx file below imports like so:

`Sentry.init({ dsn: Environment.SENTRY_DSN_DEV, environment: Environment.SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT });`

Comment: How did you integrate it can you provide a piece of code?

Comment: @J.Doe I've edited the issue. If this isn't what you're referring to, please let me know